# remove column header in vb 2010 express

Tags: vb.net

I have this application with a list box.  When a button is clicked, certain things from my db is supposed to display.  Along with the display comes column headers!!! It comes in the form of "{itemID = SW934, quantity = 10..."  and so on.  How do I get rid of the "{" and the column header???  Here is my current code:

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'MICROLANDDataSet.Orders' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.OrdersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MICROLANDDataSet.Orders)
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'MICROLANDDataSet.Inventory' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.InventoryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MICROLANDDataSet.Inventory)
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'MICROLANDDataSet.Customers' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.CustomersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MICROLANDDataSet.Customers)

End Sub

Private Sub btnOut_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOut.Click
    Dim query1 = From OUT In MICROLANDDataSet.Inventory
                 Where OUT.quantity <= 10
                 Order By OUT.description Descending
                 Select OUT.itemID, OUT.quantity, OUT.description

    lstOutput.DataSource = query1.ToList
    lstOutput.SelectedItem = Nothing


End Sub
```

End Class

Thanks guys.  Any help is VERY WELCOME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `query1` is an In-Memoery Queue Of Anonymous.  In other words, it is a enumeration of objects of an undefined type.  One way to get around this, is to concatenate your results into one string.

```
 Select OUT.itemID & OUT.quantity & OUT.description
```

and make query1 a `List(Of String)` (You can format the string any way you wish.)

Another option is to designate one of the fields as a display field.

```
lstOutput.DisplayMember="Description"
```

Comment: When you say that i can format the string any way i wish, what do you mean?

Comment: @Shinobi1173, I simply concatenated the three fields together.  However, you can create a prettier output by putting a space between the field.  `Select Out.itemID & " " & OUT.quantity & " " & Out.description`.

Comment: Man, this is really giving me a hard time.  How do I do the list(of string) portion?

Comment: @shinobi1173, what kind of results are you getting?

Comment: ok well initially, I was getting the stuff that I explained in the beginning.  After I added your suggestion (attempted), I could not get it to work since I couldnt figure out the list(to string) thing.  so i put it back to its original configuration and the craziest thing happened.  The listbox does not display anything anymore!!  The current code is exactly the same as it was before.  I dont know what the deal is...

Comment: I am also getting an error: "Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set." and it points/highlights "LstOutput.Items.Clear()"